# How can i use MapKit View in Xcode 6.3?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am unable to use MapKit in Xcode 6.3. It is showing an error when I am create property for that.
The Error is-
`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named MKMapView'`

Comment: post some code . Make sure you have added MapKit Framework in your project and  try to follow some basic tutorial like http://www.devfright.com/mkmapview-and-mkmapview-delegate-tutorial/

Comment: Right now am getting like                                                                                     -Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for location authorization. Must call -[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization] first.

Comment: http://ashishkakkad.com/2014/12/ios-8-map-kit-obj-c-get-users-location/

Comment: Am doing as it is but                                                        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
[self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];                                          these are not working, currently am using x-code 6.3.2and iOS 8.3.

Comment: As @MuhammadAdnan said: Post your code along with the specific problem you're having

Comment: Yeah it is working now thank you @Muhammad Adnan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have added MapKit Framework in your project and try to follow some basic tutorial

[IOS8 Mapkit tutorial](http://ashishkakkad.com/2014/12/ios-8-map-kit-obj-c-get-users-location/)